# Reallocate sector count, do I need to worry? [Crystal Disk Info]

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd

I recently installed an SSD as my primary boot drive and changed my existing HDD for mass storage. out of curiosity I installed [CrystalDisk](https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/) just to check the TBW of the SSD and noticed this(refer to screenshot attached) instead, I was noticing a few hiccups before SSD as well, but it looks bad, can anyone please explain what exactly these numbers refers to?

CrystalDisk Snapshot:

[image]

I already have a complete backup of my system in an external server drive so I am not worried about it.

I'm also seeing the following error as well:

```
Volume Shadow Copy Service error: Unexpected error DeviceIoControl(\\?\Volume{***************}).  hr = 0x800701b1, A device which does not exist was specified.
```

Comment: Your screenshot obscures the device model, but you're showing the HDD's information, right? I can only assume you're asking about the old HDD because most of the parameters listed there wouldn't make any sense for SSDs.

Comment: @user1686 Yes the data is from an HDD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note "**5400 rpm**", which is not relevant for an SSD, I'd say; should not be present.
You're looking at data from an HDD, holding D: and F:, not the SSD.

**Now usage hours and startup count:**
7252÷2442 = 3 hours of average usage time per start,
7252÷3 (hours per start, assuming here; per day) indicates that you have used it for 6.6 years:

I'd say - time to replace it, just based on usage time.
Possibly use it as  a scratch disk for temporary work.

Comment: Thanks @Hannu, I added a new SSD for the storage use, the current configuration is 250GB NVME boot drive, 1TB SATA SSD for storage, and 1TB old HDD, but I am still getting the `Volume Shadow Copy Service error: Unexpected error DeviceIoControl(\\?\Volume{***************}).  hr = 0x800701b1, A device which does not exist was specified.` while transferring data from HDD to SSD. is there any solution for that as well? Add yes you are correct, the data is from the HDD.

Comment: `... A device which does not exist was specified.`  - I'd guess that the drive "disconnected" in the midst of what you were doing. One simple solution; replace immediately, I hope you have a backup on your data - if not; I sincerely DO wish you "good luck" getting the data off.

Answer (score 1):

The most serious indicators for a failing disk have zero value:
"Uncorrectable Sector Count" and "Current Pending Sector Count".
This means that the disk not failing.

"Reallocated Sectors Count" is the count of bad sectors of the disk
that can no longer be trusted to safely store data. However, none
of them caused a total read/write failure
(as the above fields are empty).

A reallocated sector count above zero does not immediately mean that
the hard drive is going to fail, but it can be an early warning sign.
Your disk has thousands of spare sectors used for remapping bad sectors.
The count of 18 reallocate sectors is not excessive, and the disk
may go on to live many more years and to work just fine.

The warning sign that will tell if a drive is failing is how quickly
the reallocated sector count grows in the future.
So keep an eye on it, but there is no reason (at the moment)
to be alarmed.

Answer (score 0):

Your drive is about to die. You might freeze the current dammage status by duplicating your drive to a drive which has at least the same size and emulated sector size using GNU ddrescue.
The duplicating process may take a week or more, because you already lost around 65000 sectors which will reduce the effective duplicating speed.