CrystalDiskInfo claims my disk's health status is bad while Hard Disk Sentinel Pro claims my disk's health status is perfect. Who is right?
I have a external hard drive (Western Digital 5TB USB; WD50NDZW-11A8JS0). CrystalDiskInfo claims my disk's health status is bad while Hard Disk Sentinel Pro claims my disk's health status is perfect.
Looks like they disagree on current and worse values for Reallocated Sectors Count. How is that possible and who is right (if any)?
CrystalDiskInfo:

Hard Disk Sentinel Pro:


I use CrystalDiskInfo 8.17.2 and Hard Disk Sentinel Pro 6.20 with Windows 10 Pro.

What's "good" or "bad" in this context is a convention. Different tools use different conventions/criteria.

@ChanganAuto bad implies the disk to be changed rather soon. Do I have to change it?

Its the same 'raw' values with different, arbitrary thresholds

https://superuser.com/q/1656461/10165 related post

@JourneymanGeek thanks, "arbitrary thresholds": who chose these arbitrary thresholds? CrystalDiskInfo and Hard Disk Sentinel? Disk manufacturer?

I'd say the developers of said software. WD and other manufacturers probably have their own smart tools too

CrystalDiskInfo shows the harddisk to be too hot. I'm fairly sure that CDI is reporting the drive as bad for that reason, whereas HardDiskSential also sees the disk being hot, but not reporting that as being bad. That said, HDS says highest temperature ever measured to be lower than what it measured during the test. I'd trust CDI more, and a hot disk can cause problems in the long run. The question is: why is the disk running so hot. Is it too close to the CPU/GPU? or is it running hot from the inside? See if you can move the HDD to outside the cage and rerun the test.

I didn't catch that. Also, if its an external drive as the question reported, its the drive itself running hot.

@JoepvanSteen The CrystalDiskInfo screenshot is for a WD50NDZW-11A8JS0:
https://i.sstatic.net/HlgyexsO.png

@JoepvanSteen https://i.sstatic.net/7og2Uzke.png and https://i.sstatic.net/cQtHRRgY.png

@JoepvanSteen I think CrystalDiskInfo has a bug (CrystalDiskInfo wrongly said WD50NDZW-11A8JS0) and that you're right, I'll post a few more screenshots soon.

I'd say 'not yet, but monitor it'. Its the same 'raw' values - with different warning thresholds, as set by the developer of those applications.  I'd note this error means your hard drive compensated for bad sectors gracefully, and you still have no data loss and room to compensate for additional bad sectors.
I'd not worry too much on that alone. Disks do have some sectors that have temporary or permanent errors and unless the number rises (and frankly "current pending sector count" and "uncorrectable sector count" would worry me more - since its a sign your drive isn't compensating for failures), I'd not worry too much on its own and consider this more of a 'pre-failure' error than a sign something is terribly wrong. Its normal wear and tear (or even an acceptable amount of factory level errors).
Personally I'd also run short smart tests (and run the longer one if that fails) and consider that a better sign of  when to worry about data loss.

Thanks, are the short smart test and long smart test the same as the short/long "self-tests" https://i.sstatic.net/pBun1Hhf.png?

Yup. I didn't have my smart tool of choice installed, and went from memory ^^

Pretty sure the status comes from just the temperature being too high.

@LPChip thanks, the status doesn't come from just the temperature being too high. Example of high temperature but good health: https://i.sstatic.net/BOGUid2z.png (I was wondering that too)

tldr: a (major) bug in CrystalDiskInfo was causing incorrect Smart to be shown.
Joep van Steen's answer is correct. The screenshot:

is showing the Seagate's Smart info for current and worst values, even though  selected the WD50NDZW-11A8JS0 drive (as the screenshot says). This caused the threshold of Reallocated Sectors Count (140) to be over the current and worst values (100 for Seagate), hence the bad health status. However, the current and worst values for WD50NDZW-11A8JS0 are in fact 200, as Sentinel indicates, and as CrystalDiskInfo  realized after relaunch.
I relaunched CrystalDiskInfo and the bug was gone. Seagate:

(Note that a temperature being too high doesn't cause the health status to bad)
WD50NDZW-11A8JS0:

